# Display a message if column doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an APP, and it creates some urls based on id.

For example the edit item link opens this kind of url website.com/update_item.php?uid=1

If I change the id in url with an item id that was not created by me and I don't have access to edit it, it will display the following message: 
"You don't have access to edit this item!"

The question is, how can I display the same message to id's that do not exist in the database? How can I check either an id is or is not registered in the database?

Currently if I type in an id that does not exist it displays a blank page.

Here is the code

```
$list_id = $_GET["uid"];
$l_title = "SELECT * FROM list_items WHERE `id`='$list_id'" ;
$query = $pdo->prepare($l_title);
$query->execute();
$list = $query ->fetchAll();
```

The if code

```
if ($_SESSION['FBID'] == $item['user_id']) { 
....
```

Where `$_SESSION['FBID'`] is the logged in with facebook user and the `$item['user_id']` is the id of the user who created the list.

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: Check the result of your `SELECT` query.  If it's empty, display your special message.  Have you made any attempt at this?

Comment: use normal select query and then see if num_rows < 1 then output error `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id='yourid'`. Alternatively use `SELECT count(id) as num FROM yourtable WHERE id='yourid'` and use the value $row->num or $row['num'] depending how you fetch them and then see if num is less than 1

Comment: @RavinderReddy I edited the post

Comment: check $list, if it is empty, display the error message.

Comment: BTW, you should use `bindParam()` rather than substituting a string directly into the SQL.

Comment: @Barmar can you please give me more details?

Comment: @Radu033 http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the query results, if result is empty, display message

```
$list_id = $_GET["uid"];
$l_title = "SELECT * FROM list_items WHERE `id`='$list_id'" ;
$query = $pdo->prepare($l_title);
$query->execute();
$list = $query ->fetchAll();
if(!$list || empty($list)){
   echo "Your message";
}
```

The if code

```
if ($_SESSION['FBID'] == $item['user_id']) { 
.................
```

Comment: `empty()` is true for `false`, so you don't need to test `!$list` explicitly.

Comment: Would be nice if the prepared statement used placeholder values as this preserves the original, super dangerous SQL injection bug.

Comment: @Radu033 When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data only as arguments on `execute`. More [examples and reading here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 if($query->rowCount() < 1)
```

Alternatively use

```
$l_title = "SELECT count(id) as num FROM list_items WHERE `id`='$list_id'" ;
```

And check for

```
if($list->num < 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create 2 queries and use if statements and a while loop to verify the information like so...

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID='yourid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1){
    echo "error";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID='yourid'";

    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    } else {
        echo "could not connect to db";
    }
```

then you loop through the results like so

```
    while($result_ar = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $user = $result_ar['userinfo'];
        if($user != 'user info'){
            echo "error";
        } else {
            'do something else';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The original question is PDO. This is the wrong interface.